# Grails multiple unidirectional one-to-many not working

Tags: grails, grails-orm, one-to-many

Two of my domain classes (`User` and `Post`) have multiple one-to-many associations between them. `User` may like, dislike, see or own multiple `Post`s. For this I have set up hasMany relationship as following:

```
static hasMany = [posts:Post, seen:Post, likes:Post, dislikes:Post]
```

After developing owning side of my code when I started to work with `seen` I saw that each object that is in `posts` list is also in `seen`, `likes` and `dislikes`. Then I tried to use joinTable to map tables:

```
static mapping = {
    posts joinTable: [name: 'USER_POSTS',
        column: 'POST_ID',
        key: 'USER_ID']
    seen joinTable: [name: 'USER_SEEN',
        column: 'POST_ID',
        key: 'USER_ID']
    likes joinTable: [name: 'USER_LIKES',
        column: 'POST_ID',
        key: 'USER_ID']
    dislikes joinTable: [name: 'USER_DISLIKES',
        column: 'POST_ID',
        key: 'USER_ID']
}
```

But unfortunately nothing changed, posts added to `posts` still go to other lists too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying many `mappedBy` and `mapping` stuff I decided to create separate domains (actually with the same properties) to keep the liking, disliking and seeing connection between `User` and `Post`. Actually my solution isn't relationship based, it is a kind of log of User-Post activities.

```
class UserLike {
    static belongsTo = [user:User,post:Post]
}
class UserDislike {
    static belongsTo = [user:User,post:Post]
}
class UserSee {
    static belongsTo = [user:User,post:Post]
}
```

When I want to make some `post1` liked by `user1` I do:

```
new UserLike(user:user1,post:post1).save()
```

Maybe it isn't not be perfect for some others but solved my problem